# Try to learn exploitation with c on ubuntu

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

Im try to learn exploitation 
I starts at buffer overflow 
this is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main (int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int value=5;
    char buffer_one[8],buffer_two[8];


    strcpy(buffer_one,"one");
    strcpy(buffer_two,"two");

    printf("[+] befor 2 is at %p and have \'%s\'\n",buffer_two,buffer_two);
    printf("[+] befor 1 is at %p and have \'%s\'\n",buffer_one,buffer_one);
    printf("[+] befor value at %p and have %d (0x%08x)\n",&value,value,value);

    printf("\nstrcpy copying %d bytes into buffer_two\n\n",(int)strlen(argv[1]));
    strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]);

    printf("[+] after 2 is at %p and have \'%s\'\n",buffer_two,buffer_two);
    printf("[+] after 1 is at %p and have \'%s\'\n",buffer_one,buffer_one);
    printf("[+] after value at %p and have %d (0x%08x)\n",&value,value,value);  

    return 0;
}
```

i compiled it with the command :

```
gcc -o overflow overflow.c
```

now my problem start .

Instead of putting all the variables to the right place memory , ( first written will be at the highest memory place and last will be at lowest place and when I will fulfill the last variable with garbage it will  overwrites all the variables ) 
Their order quite strange when and the first inserted is the lowes

```
[+] befor 2 is at 0x7fffdb76e5f0 and have 'two'
[+] befor 1 is at 0x7fffdb76e5e0 and have 'one'
[+] befor value at 0x7fffdb76e5dc and have 5 (0x00000005)

strcpy copying 8 bytes into buffer_two

[+] after 2 is at 0x7fffdb76e5f0 and have '01234567'
[+] after 1 is at 0x7fffdb76e5e0 and have 'one'
[+] after value at 0x7fffdb76e5dc and have 5 (0x00000005)
```

Comment: the linker is free to adjust and malloc space as he sees fit

Comment: Regarding crash, the behavior is called Undefined Behavior (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), it never says, that it would crash for sure. There is no surety of a consistent behavior.

Comment: how can i make him to put them in the right order for me to practice?

Comment: "Exploitation" of buffer overflows is not really about overwriting other variables after the buffer. Neither the programmer nor a malicious hacker can assume that the memory allocation of variables will be after some predictable pattern. More likely, a hacker will try to overflow an input buffer on purpose to cause a program to crash, ie if the program asking "enter password" crashes upon buffer overflow, you'd bypass the whole password check.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to mention here.

1. The order of allocation of variables (in the stack) are not specified by `C` standards. Based on different level of optimization, the same compiler may reorder the allocation (thereby changing the address) for variables.
2. Accessing past the allocated memory is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Segmentation fault (the *crash*) is just *one* of the many side effects of UB.

Comment: are there is any way for me to force the compiler to compile in the "right" order for me?

Comment: @sdfgasdfsf When exploiting software, you can't assume that the compile uses the “right” order, whatever this is.